# Navigational bar issue in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am very new to PHP. I am handling a template which has been built and I am getting really confused. All I want to do is change the navigational bar names. Now normally with what I do it would be HTML but this seems to be defined in PHP and I am lost where to look.

My code is below I have targeted it down to where it is held as I have seen class in Google debugger. Now how can I find the list which is defined somewhere in my code. Which function do I go and search for next?

```
 <nav class="site-navigation<?php echo esc_attr($menu_description); ?>">
        <?php
            $locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');

            /* Check if menu is selected */

            $walker = '';
            $menu = '';
            $locations = get_theme_mod('nav_menu_locations');

            if($locations && $locations['primary']) {
                $menu = $locations['primary'];
                if( (isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'one-page') ) {
                    $menu = 21;
                }
                $walker = new description_walker();
            }

            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'container' => false,
                'menu_class' => '',
                'echo' => true,
                'before' => '',
                'after' => '',
                'link_before' => '',
                'link_after' => '',
                'depth' => 0,
                'walker' => $walker,
                'menu'=>$menu
            ));
        ?>
        <button class="fa fa-search desktop"></button>
    </nav>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Do you use WordPress for your site ? Maybe you need to do changes through admin panel? ....

Comment: By "Google debugger", do you mean the developer tools in Chrome? (I've retagged as WordPress, as this clearly looks like a WP site).

Comment: yeah.. sorry i never ever use WP and i dont really know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your issue is not in the code, as the above snippet is simply defining the menus for use through the WP admin.

Login to the back-end and visit Appearance > Menus and you should see a menu here, or the ability to create one.

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks so much i have never used wp so i was like wtf lol and the code was killing me